# Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a static chat application using php and mysql, here's the code to display the messages in the chat box

```
$sql="SELECT id,msg,time,msg.from,msg.to from msg WHERE (msg.from='".$_SESSION["username"]."' OR msg.from='".$_SESSION["tousermessage"]."') AND (msg.to='".$_SESSION["tousermessage"]."' OR msg.to='".$_SESSION["username"]."') ORDER BY time";
$ex=$conn->prepare($sql);
$ex->execute();

echo "<div class='text-wrap'>";
while($result=$ex->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if ($result['from']==$_SESSION["username"])
    {
        echo "<div class='message-view' >"; 
        echo "<b class='name'>".$_SESSION["username"]."</b></br>";
        echo "<p class='subject'>".$result["msg"]."</p><p class='time'>".$result["time"]."</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class='message-view' style='background-color: rgb(216, 236, 244);'>";    
        echo "<b class='name'>".$_SESSION["tousermessage"]."</b><br>";
        echo "<p class='subject'>".$result["msg"]."</p><p class='time'>".$result["time"]."</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    if($result['to']==$_SESSION['username'])
    {
        $sqlupdate="UPDATE msg SET readmsg=1 WHERE id=".$result['id']." and msg='".$result["msg"]."'";      
        $ex1=$conn->prepare($sqlupdate);
        $ex1->execute();
    }
}
echo "</div>";
```

Sometimes it shows the exception:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound.

The message gets inserted in the msg table but the error occurs during displaying the message. The error occurs randomly at the sender's side or the receiver side or both sides. I cannot find a pattern or the reason why it is occurring!

Comment: You mention that this happens after insertions, but the code you've posted doesn't contain any `INSERT` statements...

Comment: Sorry! Corrected it!

Comment: You should add diagnostic output to show the command which caused the failure. Note however that you have a bigger problem - your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using bind_param, as per the prepared statement paradigm.

In your select:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,msg,time,msg.from,msg.to 
        FROM msg 
        WHERE msg.from IN (?, ?) 
            AND msg.to IN (?, ?)
        ORDER BY time";

$ex = $conn->prepare($sql);
$ex->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["username"]);
$ex->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["tousermessage"]);
$ex->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["username"]);
$ex->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["tousermessage"]);
$ex->execute();
```

And in your update:

```
$sql = "UPDATE msg 
        SET readmsg=1 
        WHERE id = ? 
            AND msg = ?";

$ex1 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$ex1->bind_param("i", $result['id']);
$ex1->bind_param("s", $result["msg"]);
$ex1->execute();
```

The above allows your prepared statement to accept parameters in the parameterized string format (using "?" to represent a param), and to accept params with type information, via the bind_param() method.

This allows the DB engine to properly cast and escape params prior to executing your query.

There's no point using prepared statements if you're not binding params, which is probably why you're getting that warning.

On a side note, concatenation of queries (as you're doing above) is a very bad habit - it opens you up to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

---

See the docs for more info on prepared statements:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Comment: But shouldn't the warning come before displaying the first message? Why does it seem to occur after a random message?

Comment: The code above isnt' writing msg.msg at all.  I suspect you have a similar problem in your `INSERT` statement (which you didn't post here).  Switch all your prepared statements to the above paradigm, and you should be all set.